# Query contacts by name using Office 365 Rest API

Tags: office365

Is it possible to search contacts by name (GiveName, DisplayName, LastName or Surname) using the OData filters?

Here's the documentation I'm using: [Office 365 API OData filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparametersFilterrequests)

I see in the documentation where they say some properties cannot be filtered but they don't give a full list (complex types are listed but they don't include contact names).

My guess is no because when I try:

```
/contacts?$filter=DateTimeCreated+ge+2014-09-01T00:00:00Z
```

I get a 200 response with correct data but when I try by any of the name properties:

```
/contacts?$filter=DisplayName+eq+Jordan+Example
/contacts?$filter=LastName+eq+Example
/contacts?$filter=Surname+eq+Example
```

I get 400 Bad Response with no details in the response body but I know (and double checked) that the contact exists.

Would also love to search with a wildcard but trying not to be too greedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, but you need to wrap your values in single quotes ('). Try:

```
/contacts?$filter=DisplayName eq 'Jordan Example'
/contacts?$filter=LastName eq 'Example'
/contacts?$filter=Surname eq 'Example'
```

Comment: Is it possible to search on name like when I looking for all contacts where the givenName starts with Mi